# How can i post all my selected items in nestable

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using nestable.js bootstrap with checkbox and every item gets re-positioned doesn't show up on the output. Is there a way so my output gets re-arranged the way it being nested with all the items checked are included in the output?

my code:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="custom-dd dd" id="nestable_list">
  <ol class="dd-list">
//loop start
<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$checkbox_nr.'">
<div class="dd-handle">
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success col-10 dd-nodrag">
<input type="checkbox" class="ch_filled" id="ch_filled-'.$checkbox_nr.'" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$rPacklist['id'].'">
<label for="ch_filled-'.$checkbox_nr.'">'.$rPackTrim.'</label>
</div>
</div>
</li>
//loop end
  </ol>
</div>
</form>

<script>
$('.dd').nestable({ maxDepth:1 });
</script>
```

Without dragging output is correct, but if i re-position any item, my PHP only detect items not being dragged/re-positioned on submit.

PHP output example:

```
Array ( [0] => 280 )
```

Comment: I usually use ajax to submit my sortable form lists - that way I can iterate the DOM in order to ensure the proper resorted order